# Setting an ASP TextBox's enabled property using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm getting "CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'bool'" as an error message when trying to set the enabled property of an ASP TextBox.

The Markup is as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="dateTo" runat="server" Enabled='<%# "javascript:disableDateTo()"%>' BackColor="#FFFF99" />
```

And the Javascipt function is:

```
function disableDateTo() {
    // Disable the dateTo field if the dateFrom field doesn't contain a value
    if ($("#MainContent_dateFrom").datepicker("getDate") != null) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: ASP.Net does not work like that.  You cannot mix server-side and client-side code.

Comment: You're mixing up server-side and client-side code here. Why use server-side inline stuff but put client-side JavaScript in it? Not to mention your "extra" quotes (single _and_ double ...why?)

Comment: no server-side language does actually work like this. You just can't call client (javascript) functions from your server-side code , and vice-versa. Also, I would strongly advise to remove styling information from your aspx page and move it to a css file.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments that you can't mix server side and client side code like you have in your example. It looks like what you want is something that will accept a date as text input, until a user picks a date from the calendar. If that is the case, I would implement it as pure client-side code, as [follows](http://jsfiddle.net/3mtLd/1/):

Html:

```
<div id='MainContent_dateFrom'></div>
<input id='dateTo' type='text' />
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#MainContent_dateFrom").datepicker({
        onSelect: function() {
            $("#dateTo").val(new Date(Date.parse($(this).datepicker("getDate"))).toLocaleDateString())
                .attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a JavaScript event to fire outside of the asp .net control markup.
Here is how you would achieve this using the page load as an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    disable();
});

function disable() {
    if ($("#dateTo[disabled]").length > 0) {
        $("#dateTo").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $("#dateTo").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}
</script>
```